# How to allow Allow full access to all Cloud APIs (For Cloud API access scopes) from Deployment jinja template in google cloud platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jinja2, google-deployment-manager

I am new to GCP and want to create a Test drive. I have been trying to create a VM instance from an existing image from a deployment template and am successful in doing so. I followed [This doc](https://cloud.google.com/launcher/docs/partners/test-drive-single-vm), but I want to allow full access to all Cloud APIs for Cloud API access scopes.[This is the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXk9W.png) which shows the feature of VM instance. 
I want to enable it from my jinja template file (YML format file)

Comment: Do you know if there are security risks for granting full access?  Why is the default limited to fewer permissions?

Answer (score 6):

You have to setup up the appropriate scope for your `serviceAccounts` when you create the instance:

```
- name: {{ vmName }}
  type: compute.v1.instance
  properties:
...
    serviceAccounts:
    - email: default
      scopes:
        - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform
...
```

use `cloud-platform` scope to allow full access to all Cloud APIs.

Comment: Do you know if there are security risks for granting full access?  Why is the default limited to fewer permissions?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the [--scope flag](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/instances/create#--scopes). If you exclude this flag, the instance is created with default API access. The --scope flag is followed by a comma separated list of scope aliases or URLs. You'll have to list each API you want enabled on the instance.

Comment: Do you know if there are security risks for granting full access?  Why is the default limited to fewer permissions?

Comment: The default service account has the editor role. with full scope available, the instance will allow any user or application to have full permissions on any gcp resource. This is a huge security risk. You should only use the cloud-plarform scope if you use a custom service account with specific permissions

Comment: I am facing an issue when using a custom service account instead of default here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73800457/unable-to-assign-service-account-to-instance?noredirect=1#comment130322855_73800457. Please advise