# Unable to assign service account to Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-deployment-manager

I am using the below jijna instance creation template in GCP. When I create this I get the below error.

I have already tried giving even Owner and iam.serviceAccountUser permission to xxxxxxxxxx@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com account.

I have also added xxxxxxxxxx@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com user with iam.serviceAccountUser role under Access control section as member in my new service account I have created which is test-vm-gke-init-vm@.iam.gserviceaccount.com.

```
ERROR: (gcloud.deployment-manager.deployments.update) Error in Operation [operation-1663746707027-5e92b3777f488-7748cc3b-a3d3cc8f]: errors:
- code: RESOURCE_ERROR
  location: /deployments/demo-vm/resources/test-vm
  message: "{\"ResourceType\":\"compute.v1.instance\",\"ResourceErrorCode\":\"SERVICE_ACCOUNT_ACCESS_DENIED\"\
    ,\"ResourceErrorMessage\":\"The user does not have access to service account 'serviceAccount:test-vm-gke-init-vm@<myproject>.iam.gserviceaccount.com'.\
    \  User: 'xxxxxxxxxx@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com'.  Ask a project owner\
    \ to grant you the iam.serviceAccountUser role on the service account\"}"
```

```
resources:
- type: compute.v1.instance
  name: {{ properties.name }}
  properties:
    machineType: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{{ env["project"] }}/zones/{{ properties["zone"] }}/machineTypes/{{ properties["machineType"] }}
    zone: {{ properties["zone"] }}
    disks:
    - deviceName: boot
      type: PERSISTENT
      boot: true
      autoDelete: true
      initializeParams:
        diskName: disk-{{ env["deployment"] }}
        sourceImage: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/debian-cloud/global/images/debian-11-bullseye-v20220822
    networkInterfaces:
    - network: https://www.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/{{ env["project"] }}/global/networks/default
      accessConfigs:
      - name: External NAT
        type: ONE_TO_ONE_NAT  
    serviceAccounts: 
    - email: serviceAccount:$(ref.{{ properties.name }}-sa.email) 
      scopes:
      - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only
      - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write
      - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring.write
      - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/servicecontrol
      - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/service.management.readonly
      - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute
      - https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform


- name: {{ properties.name }}-sa
  type: gcp-types/iam-v1:projects.serviceAccounts
  properties:
    accountId: {{ properties.name }}-gke-init-vm
    displayName: {{ properties.name }}-gke-init-vm
  accessControl:
    gcpIamPolicy:
      bindings:
      - role: roles/iam.serviceAccountUser
        members:
        - "serviceAccount:<myproject>@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com"

- name: {{ env["project"] }}-{{ properties.name }}-initnode-sa-binding
  type: gcp-types/cloudresourcemanager-v1:virtual.projects.iamMemberBinding
  properties:
    resource: {{ env["project"] }}
    member: serviceAccount:$(ref.{{ properties.name }}-sa.email)
    role: roles/container.clusterAdmin 



- name: {{ env["project"] }}-{{ properties.name }}-initnode-sa-binding-v2
  type: gcp-types/cloudresourcemanager-v1:virtual.projects.iamMemberBinding
  properties:
    resource: {{ env["project"] }}
    member: serviceAccount:$(ref.{{ properties.name }}-sa.email)
    role: roles/container.admin
```

Comment: Only somewhat confident but you will need to grant `roles/iam.serviceAccountUser` **outside** (and before) you try the Cloud Deployment. I think it's the Cloud Deployment service itself (operating as `xxxxxxxxxx@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com`) that needs the permission. You can use Cloud Console or `gcloud` to do this.

Comment: Yes I have tried giving that permission to xxxxxxxxxx@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com, but still gets this error

Comment: is `xxxxxxxxxx@cloudservices.gserviceaccount.com` service account from the same project as `test-vm-gke-init-vm@<myproject>.iam.gserviceaccount.com`? Are all these resources in the same project?

Comment: Ya all are from same project

Comment: this probably won't change anything, but remove the extra scopes. You have `cloud-platform` as a scope defined, you don't need any others. Also check GCP access logs to see if the same error message appears, it should include the action attempted and give more details

Comment: Thanks @PatrickW . This was fix. The reason was I was "serviceAccount:" again while the reference was already containing it. I only had to specify the reference which is $(ref.{{ properties.name }}-sa.email)

Answer (score 0):

For reference for other communities for this issue

specify the reference below to resolve the issue.

```
$(ref.{{ properties.name }}-sa.email)
```